# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86 Current browser version is 89.0.4389.90

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, bots

**Error Message:**

`This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86  Current browser version is 89.0.4389.90 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe.`

Even though I have updated my **chromedriver**, my program is showing this error. How to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Aathira! How is this question related to the `python` tag, would you care to elaborate? What were you trying to do before the error, is there any relevant code you might want to post here? After you update your question with more details, will it be [suitable for this website](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 1):

You issue, because the version of the chromedriver is not valid for current version of the browser, download the newest one.
Try webdriver-manager library:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

and launch your code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```